# Pass a value to a Form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have to pass a value in a form where the user cannot to choose. I have a Register model with some fields. One of them is a value from another Model called Car. I show in the _form view the car plate value but I want to link this value in the form This is the code in _form :

```
 <%= form_for(@reg) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
    <p><%= f.label :date %></p><br>
<%= f.date_field :date_reg %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
<p><%= f.label :car_id %></p><br>
<% Car.all.each do |car| %>
<%= car.plate %>
<%= f.select(:driver_id, 
               options_from_collection_for_select(Driver.all, :id, 
               :name), {:prompt => 'Please Choose'}, :class => "form- 
               control")     %><br>
     <% end %>
    </div>
 <div class="field">

 </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks all

Comment: If you want to pass value to this form you can define `@plate` variable in method in controller from where you are rendering this form

Comment: And you can use `hidden_field_tag` in your form if you need to pass a variable to your controller [on form submission] that the user has no control over.

Comment: The user has plenty of control over it, so make sure not to use it as a secure way of preventing the user from selecting a particular car.

Comment: I think the same about the hidden field. thanks

Comment: Good call on the control and security. I meant having no obvious control.